# In entity framework core, how we can set relationship for a table, when two fields is mapping to primary key of the another table

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

In entity framework core, how we can set relationship for a table, when two fields is mapping to primary key of the another table.
For example I have two table namely Users & CashBox.

**Users Table**

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| UserId | int |
| UserName | string |

**CashBox Table**

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CashBoxId | int |
| ActivatedBy | int |
| DeactivatedBy | int |

In this case, activatedby & deactivatedby has to be linked with user table. Need to know who activated cashbox & who deactivated cashbox.

Using EF core code first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following entity models -

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class CashBox
{
    [Key]
    public int CashBoxId { get; set; }
    public int ActivatedBy { get; set; }
    public int DeactivatedBy { get; set; }

    public User ActivatedUser { get; set; }
    public User DeactivatedUser { get; set; }
}
```

you can configure the relationship as -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CashBox>(e =>
    {
        e.HasOne(p => p.ActivatedUser)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ActivatedBy);

        e.HasOne(p => p.DeactivatedUser)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.DeactivatedBy);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Am getting following error,\n Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [CashBox] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CashBox_Users_DeactivatedBy] FOREIGN KEY ([DeactivatedBy]) REFERENCES [Users] ([UserId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;

Comment: When is this showing? Also, what database system are you using?